# "Increasing" Vs "Additional"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

Consider:

> The network suffers from additional users.

I think It declares that if the number of users exceeds a specific number, the network will have to deal with some problems.

I have used the adjective "**additional**" several times. I want to imply the same connotation but, it really bothers me to overuse a word in a piece of writing. I came up with:

> The network suffers from increasing numbers of users.

Can I use ***increasing*** in this context if I have to avoid using adjectives like ***extra***, ***excessive***, ***further***.

---

Personal Statement:

I think ***increasing*** would convey the general sense of growth no matter how much this expansion is  big. something similar to ever-growing.

Comment: Increasing is a better term, but there are other times in which additional may be a stronger word for the subject. (Just an opinion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "increasing" works OK. It does suggest something that is growing. It's not precise, though. The network doesn't suffer because the number of users increases; the network suffers because there are too many people using it. I would suggest "ever-increasing" instead. It's a relatively common phrase that's a little stronger than "increasing." It implies the network is *always* growing -- and therefore is also difficult to maintain.  I think it gets to the heart of what you want to say.

Comment: Thanks, but the context is merely a mathematical conclusion. something similar to: increasing numbers of users will bring about further power consumption. It seems I was not successful in choosing a proper example.

Comment: OK, this might work then: *The network suffers as the number of users increases.* Or: *The network suffers proportionately **to** the increase in the number of users.* If you're trying to state something mathematical, I think *number of users* is more appropriate than *numbers of users*, simply because a network **can** precisely count the number of logged-in users.

Comment: That **s** in ***users*** is due to the present participle ***increasing***. In the first version of the question I had written " number of users" which faced with Catija's incisive objection

Comment: If it's a large network with multiple hubs, then maybe "numbers" is more appropriate. I personally would go with singular "number," because it implies that this is a precise, technical statement.

Comment: In fact he said, choose "**an increasing number of**" or "**increasing numbers of**". consider a general statement: increasing numbers of people will increase the weight of the elevator.

Comment: I think you can use either, but "increasing numbers" (plural) suggests a large, vague number. For example: *the migrating herds of gazelle*.  Unless it were a very large and very fast elevator in a very busy office building, I think "an increasing number" (singular) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, "additional" and "increasing" can be interchanged.

> additional

usually means a single increase, where as

> increasing

will usually mean a continuously greater amount.

> The network suffered from *increasing* usage due to *additional* users and Euro 2016 last month.

Comment: Thanks, BTW question: "increasing number of" or "increasing numbers of"

Comment: "Increasing number of users", "increasing numbers of football fans", "increasing number of German football fans"